# Select lowest value in table where lowest value less than

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
table_a
id | charge
1  |   95 
1  |   1
2  |   25
```

I want to select the lowest charge from each id and determine if its less than...for example
SELECT id,charge FROM table_a WHERE MIN(charge) > 10 GROUP BY id

```
Results:
None
```

SELECT id,charge FROM table_a WHERE MIN(charge) < 10 GROUP BY id

```
Results:
id | charge
1  |   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `having` clause:

```
SELECT id, min(charge)
FROM table_a
group by id
having MIN(charge) < 10
```

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS...THIS WAS WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR...THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should work, unless I'm missing something:

```
SELECT id, MIN(charge)
WHERE charge BETWEEN 10 AND 40
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an aggregate function in a `WHERE` clause - it has to be in a `HAVING` clause - but in your case you're filtering on row-level values rather than aggregates so something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT id, MIN(charge)
FROM table_a
WHERE charge BETWEEN 10 AND 40
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I know I cant do that its an example of what I want, the problem is that if I have several ids with the same number the MIN() will not be taken into place

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood. In that case (assuming I understand the requirement now) the @GordonLinoff answer is at least on the right track. If not, could you supply a few more sample rows and maybe an example of how a number outside the 10-40 range will mess up the results?